# Terminology about trees

Tags: set-theory, terminology, posets, trees

In set theory, a tree is usually defined as a partial order such that the set of elements below any given one is well-ordered.  I am interested in the class of partial orders $P$ such that for every $p \in P$, the set of $q \leq p$ is just *linearly* ordered. Does this have a name?

Comment: https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00571186

Comment: Prefix orders seem to be relevant, if for no other reason than they appear to fit the required definitional niche. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_order

Comment: Thanks @NotMike!  It's nice to see this coming from outside of pure set theory.  Feel free to put this as an answer.

Comment: Adeleke and Neumann have a Memoir of the AMS 'Relations related to betweenness' which considers various structures along these lines. In particular, a partially ordered set satisfying the property above which is also assumed to be connected (every pair of elements has a common lower bound) is called a *semilinearly ordered set*. I don't know if they have a name for such objects if they're not connected.

Answer (score 11):

They are also called trees.

In that terminology, trees of your first kind are known as the *well-founded* trees, since they are trees where the tree order is well-founded (and well-founded linear orders are the same as well-orders).

I think that the situation is that because set theorists are mainly interested in the well-founded case, the terminology evolved to drop the adjective from well-founded trees.

There are many competing definitions of *tree* in mathematics, not all equivalent. For graph-theorists, for example, a tree is a certain kind of cycle-free graph.

Comment: This is also what I thought off the top of my head, but Jech, Kunen, and Kanamori all put well-foundedness into the definition of a tree. Do you know of a reference the defines trees as the more general class?

Comment: Well, those are all set theory references, and so they use the set theory convention, which as we said is focused on the well-founded case. I've seen the linearly ordered version sometimes in talks, but I don't know a specific reference. And in truth, I think that the non-well-founded tree case is simply much less studied. For finite trees, however, saying linear is enough (for every finite order is well-founded), and one can definitely find that.

Comment: I guess the complication also is that "well-founded tree" now means something else in set theory, where the tree is growing downward and has no infinite branches.

Comment: For one reference: Keisler uses the linear order definition in his article "Models with tree structures".

Full citation:

H. Jerome Keisler. “Models with tree structures”. In: Proceedings  of  the  Tarski  Symposium (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XXV, Univ. California, Berkeley, Calif., 1971) . Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1974, pp. 331–348.

Comment: But set-theoreticians, who use the word "tree" to mean well-founded tree, must occasionally have to refer to the more general trees. What do they call them? If I use "tree" to mean a poset in which the predecessors of any element are well-ordered, then what should I call a poset in which the predecessors of any element are linearly ordered? I have some vague recollection of hearing them called "pseudotrees" or something like that.

Comment: Those kind of trees aren't often considered, but I would just call them trees, and remark on the variant usage for that purpose. Some people might use pseudo tree, but I find that terminology regrettable, as clearly the linearly ordered version is a fundamental and genuine tree concept, of which the well-ordered version is a special case.

Comment: @bof A colleague pointed me to several set-theory papers by Koppelberg-Monk, Bekkali, and Alos-Ferrer and Ritzberger, where the term pseudotree is used for exactly this kind of poset.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Upgraded from a comment:

After a little bit of searching, the notion of *prefix order* seems to be relevant; if for no other reason than that it appears to fit the required [definitional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_order#Formal_definition) niche.

(Also, it seemed worth pointing out the notion of prefix-order is precisely that of a "first-order tree".)